# Window Phone silverlight 8.1 HttpNotificationChannel ChannelUriUpdated not being hit

Tags: c#, silverlight, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

I have a very basic Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 app that contains the following (I want to prove the concept before adding it to a much larger pre-existing app):

```
HttpNotificationChannel pushChannel;

void registerPushChannel()
{
   pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);

   // If the channel was not found, then create a new connection to the push service.
   if (pushChannel == null)
   {
      pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName);

      // Register for all the events before attempting to open the channel.
      pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
      pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);
      pushChannel.HttpNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<HttpNotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_HttpNotificationReceived);

      pushChannel.Open();

   }
   else
   {
      // The channel was already open, so just register for all the events.
      pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
      pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);
      pushChannel.HttpNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<HttpNotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_HttpNotificationReceived);

      // code which passes the new channel URI back to my web service     
    }
}

void PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated(object sender, NotificationChannelUriEventArgs e)
{
   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
   {
       // Display the new URI for testing purposes. Normally, the URI would be passed back to your web service at this point.
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ChannelUri.ToString());
       MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}",
                    e.ChannelUri.ToString()));

     });
 }
```

The problem is the PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated never gets hit and i just cant figure out why!

I've set ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION in my WMAppManifest.xml and also 
Toast Capable = yes in my Package.appmanifest....what sneakery am I missing ?

Comment: Where you get problem ?

Comment: pushChannel.Uri is always null after  pushChannel.Open(); and connectionstatus is disconnected. and then wheni call NotificationHub hub = new NotificationHub(hubName, connectionString);
            await hub.RegisterNativeAsync(pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString());   it throws a NullReferenceException on RegisterNativeAsync

Comment: Have you try my posted answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I had tried below code for Notification :

```
HttpNotificationChannel pushChannel;
```

Put pushChannel as globle in App.xaml.cs file it's use in `EventHandler`

```
string channelName = "PushChannel";
pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);
//Push Notifications
if (pushChannel == null)
{
    pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName);

    //// Register for all the events before attempting to open the channel.
    pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
    pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

    // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
    pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

    pushChannel.Open();

    // Bind this new channel for toast events.
    pushChannel.BindToShellToast();
}
else
{
    // The channel was already open, so just register for all the events.
    pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
    pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

    // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
    pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

    // Display the URI for testing purposes. Normally, the URI would be passed back to your web service at this point.enter code here
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        //pushURI = pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString();
        //MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}", pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString()));
        Notification.ChannelURI = pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString();
    });
}
```

Put above code in your App.xaml.cs file in `App()`

**Events :**

```
void PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated(object sender, NotificationChannelUriEventArgs e1)
{
    try
    {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}", e1.ChannelUri.ToString()));
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
}
void PushChannel_ErrorOccurred(object sender, NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs e2)
{
    try
    {
        // Error handling logic for your particular application would be here.
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(String.Format("A push notification {0} error occurred.  {1} ({2}) {3}", e2.ErrorType, e2.Message, e2.ErrorCode, e2.ErrorAdditionalData));
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
}
```

Comment: thank you - i should have been more precise...after the pushChannel.Open(); the pushChannel Uri is null and connectionstatus is disconnected.

Comment: @BzBurr I got **ChannelUri** in `PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated` event have get ChannelUri

Comment: @BzBurr please check your configuration

Comment: @BzBurr `PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated` is not call every time, it's call when `HttpNotificationChannel` **is not found** OR `null`

Comment: ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION is on , ID_CAP_NETWORKING is on , the app is Toast Capable...what might i be missing?

Comment: In `WMAppManifest.xml` file Application UI has listpicker which value you have selected ?

Comment: it is selected to MPN -

Comment: @BzBurr As per you say your configure all. So, Now Last thing you to check go configuration again and put break point and check.